# Importing PHP file in Flash doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, xml, flash

I'm extracting data from MySQL into flash. First I use PHP to query the DB, and then I echo the results.

```
$sql = "SELECT path FROM video WHERE id = 52";
$resource = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<video>\n";
echo "<path>" . $row['path'] . "</path>\n";
echo "</video>\n";
```

I only have one root element, and I don't see anything wrong with my markup following the root element...but then again I'm wrong and I'm sure there is an error.

**--- Changed my Title so I added the error message here ---**

```
  TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

------**EDITED** ------

The value of $row['path'] is a string from my DB. I know it's valid because I deleted all xml tags and echoed $row['path'] which is the url path for the video. I also used gettype(), and it outputs a string.

When I open this file into my browser, I actually don't see anything. It's a blank page, but it's because the browser is rendering it as html elements, so I don't think that's the problem. But when I view source, I get this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<video>
<path>1.mp4</path>
</video>
```

In addition, I created a random file with an xml extension with the xml contents above, (copied it form View Source that my php file outputs) and it  works fine. I see the contents in Flash. What could be wrong with echoing it out in a php file? I'm using textWrangler. It might have something to do with BOM, any suggestions?

**----EDIT NUMBER TWO ---**

Here's my actionscript code. I'm still new so I didn't put it in a class but inside the first frame in my actions layer. I'm just trying to get the basics to work.

```
var theXML:XML;
var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../folderExample/poop.php");
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

function  xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
     theXML = new XML(xmlLoader.data); // The Error occurs here.
     trace(theXML.toXMLString());
}

xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
```

Comment: what's `$row['path']`'s value? e.g. what does the xml look like AFTER php outputs it?

Comment: I edited my question above. The value is the path to my video, and I think it's valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echoing xml in PHP gives blank pages in Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145446/echoing-xml-in-php-gives-blank-pages-in-browser)

Comment: Never-ever duplicate your own question. You did. I closed reversed wrong order, it should have been otherwise. This was a mistake of mine. If you complain, do so. I've flagged for moderator attention anyway.

Comment: what... I didn't... that question is not that same as this question. The question you linked was specific to a blank page showing in the browser. The answer was that the browser was rendering the output of php... and now I know that a blank page has nothing to do with the Flash error message which this question addresses. I don't want to be rude, but maybe you should read the questions.

Comment: By the way, the only reason I asked the question you linked was to find a solution by eliminating anything I thought was the source of the problem. I thought the blank page was part of the problem. It's not. Echoing contents in the php file in the browser is not the same as uploading the php file into Flash.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=3128

> For well-formed XML returning 
>   TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed, 
>   often the problem is the BOM.
>
> Actionscript XML does not strip the BOM (Byte Order Mark) from incoming text. The BOM is an invisible character (#65279) created at the beginning of a ASP or php "echo" string, as well as some text editors, to indicate the byte-ordering of multibyte text.
>
> You can confirm if your string has this BOM character like this:
>
> `trace( sXMLString.charCodeAt( 0 ) ); //outputs 65279`
>
> The quick solution is
>
> `sXMLString= sXMLString.replace( String.fromCharCode(65279), "" ) ;`
>
> `myXML = new XML(sXMLString);`

See also:

[Reading php generated XML in flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413266/reading-php-generated-xml-in-flash?rq=1)

[How to load PHP dynamically generated XML in FLASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390896/how-to-load-php-dynamically-generated-xml-in-flash?rq=1)

If you don't have it already, from the second link above, try adding:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Except I checked this site for any BOM ...http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/#validate-by-upload+... and it returns no BOM found. I think this is accurate because I also created another file and set my configuration in my text editor to UTF-8 with BOM, resubmitted, and the validator returned a confirmation for BOM.

Comment: Are you sending the proper header from your PHP file? Updated with example.

Comment: Wasn't before, but now I am. The error stills shows though. I'm going to look online to see if my actionscript code is even correct. Again, thanks! I would upvote your answer but my reputation is too low