# Echoing xml in PHP gives blank pages in Browser

Tags: php, xml, flash

I have a similar question to this:
https://superuser.com/questions/140242/why-my-browsers-display-xml-files-as-blank-pages?rq=1

I don't see my xml in my browser, but just a blank page. I only checked Chrome and firefox, but it's happening in both.
The difference is that I'm getting data from MySQL and echoing it. So the file extension is .php and not .xml

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource);
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<video>\n";
echo "<path>" . $row['path'] . "</path>\n";
echo "</video>\n";
```

I see a blank page when I go to the url. But when I "View Source", I see the xml tree.

```
<video>
 <path>URLtoVideo.mp4</path>
</video>
```

My main goal is to grab the xml data and request it in Flash using URLRequest(). But I get this error

```
TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be    well-formed.
```

I think this may be the problem to the error I get in Flash. I only have one root node, and I don't think I have any problems with the child nodes. So my only assumption is that the error occurs because of the blank page.

Comment: This is a common mistake. A lack of understanding how the foundation of HTML and XML are the same and the browser just displaying "as best" the XML which has been marketed as HTML. It's not that the problem of display has been become better over the years, it's just a lack of understanding of *you* how you deal with data - out of the blue. If there is anything that can help you to understand why you don't see the output (e.g. "view source" normally helps), just let me know via comments.

Comment: And as a sidenote: If you've got problems with non-well-formed XML, use an XML library to create the XML - don't just concatenate strings. Again, if you want to learn more about that, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is not displayed because the browser interpret it.

When you write

```
<table></table>
```

In your HTML page, you will not see the string

```
"<table><table\>"
```

But an empty table.

This is the same things about XML content.

Another Stack overflow post got an answer to this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page)

Here I copy past the answer of mellamokb

> Simple solution is to embed inside of a  element, which will
>   preserve both the formatting and the angle brackets. I have also
>   removed the border with style="border:none;" which makes the textarea
>   invisible.
>
> Here is a sample: xxxx

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense. The only reason I was worried about the blank page was because I thought it was the reason that flash was returning the error. I copied my xml from my "View Source" and pasted it to W3school validator, and it passed. Now that I know the blank page isn't the problem, I can now narrow the source of error. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: np, gl with your work :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an XML header before your output. Your browser is trying to read it like HTML otherwise

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make and xml object/element and then echo it, plus dont forget to add `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` before echo.

For more refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php